# What are the options to mask data in Oracle standard edition (SE2)?

Tags: oracle

We have an Oracle Database Standard Edition 2 (SE2), and we need to mask some data. The only option I've considered is creating views only with allowed columns. Is there any other way in the standard edition? `Data Masking` and `Redaction` are not allowed in the standard edition.

Comment: Creating views with built-in redaction in a separate API schema would be the simplest way to go.